# Doing Hart's Rails Tutorial, but server won't shut down for me fire it up after updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide

I have made some changes to various files, and need to shut down and then restart the server to see them. I am using the Cloud9 railstutorial environment. But I keep getting the same error - "A server is already running". Please see below:

```
darrenbrett:~/workspace/sample_app (filling-in-layout) $ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

A server is already running. Check /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/tmp/pids/server.pid.
Exiting
darrenbrett:~/workspace/sample_app (filling-in-layout) $
```

Answer (score 3):

Find out the process id (`PID`) first:

```
$ lsof -wni tcp:8080
```

This will give you something like this:

```
$ lsof -wni tcp:8080 

COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    59656 rislam   14u  IPv6 0xa86b8563672ef037      0t0  TCP [::1]:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

Then, kill the process with `PID = 59656 (for example, it will be different for you)`:

```
$ kill -9 59656
```

This should solve your problem.

You can also use the following command to kill all running apps that has `rails` in the name:

```
killall -9 rails
```

Sometimes, this is very effective when the first command does not do the trick.

Comment: This is great- I didn't know about searching by port until now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you either have an orphaned server process running, or you have multiple applications in the same environment and you're running the server for another one and it's bound to the same port.  I'm guessing the former.

Run `ps -fe | grep rails`.  You should see something like `501 35861  2428   0  1:55PM ttys012    0:04.00 /your_file_path/ruby bin/rails server`

Grab the process id (in the case of the example, it's 35861), and run `kill -9 35861`.  Then try to start your server again.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found to kill that server is to click on the suggested file in the line:

```
A server is already running. Check /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/tmp/pids/server.pid
```

That opens the file containing a number, the process id you're looking for.

Example

```
43029
```

In the terminal window use "kill" via that same process id and restart the server.

```
kill -15 43029
rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
```