# RoR - " A Server is already running" - How do I kill the runing server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

Another newbie moment- I am trying to run a local server in cloud 9 IDE.
It seems that I already have another server running. I tried to kill it using :
rake tmp:clear

That didn't seem to work.

Here is the message I am getting :

=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.rc2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
A server is already running. Check /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/tmp/pids/server.pid.
Exiting

As always, thanks in advance for your help.

J

Comment: favorite this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4473322/1301840

Comment: When I run lsof -wni tcp:3000   PID number doesn't show up. I am on windows.

Comment: You run it in your server. Not your local computer. :|

Comment: enter cltr+c to shutdown the server

Comment: try this https://docs.c9.io/docs/process-list

Comment: Thanks AAkudovich. It's a great resource what you posted. I should definitely get acquainted more with cloud9. The app is running on a Puma. It's running fine. My main question became what the difference between a puma server and a WEBrick server. My understanding is that WEBrick is the default server . I wonder in which cases it goes into puma.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

run `ps aux | grep rails` then find the pid of the process. To kill it, run `sudo kill -9 pid_number`

Comment: ubuntu     14458  0.0  0.0  10556  1660 pts/1    S+   00:38   0:00 grep --color=auto rails          is 14458 the PID ?

Comment: Perfect! I didn't need to use `sudo`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Find out the process id (PID) first:

```
$ lsof -wni tcp:8080
```

This will give you something like this:

```
$ lsof -wni tcp:8080 

COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    59656 rislam   14u  IPv6 0xa86b8563672ef037      0t0  TCP [::1]:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

Then, kill the process with PID = 59656 (for example, it will be different for you):

```
$ kill -9 59656
```

This should solve your problem.

You can also use the following command to kill all running apps that has rails in the name:

```
killall -9 rails
```

Sometimes, this is very effective when the first command does not do the trick.

credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33456222/5830835

Answer (score 1):

```
lsof -i tcp:3000

kill -9 PID
```

OR

Goto RAILS.root/tmp/pids/server.pid file and delete all content and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Enter Ctrl + C, that should shoutdown the server

Comment: Ctrl +C and Ctrl +D are not working. They work but the server still runs

Comment: Try changing the port     rails server -p 8080

Comment: how do I do that ?  rails server -p 8080 ? still the same message : A server is already running. Check /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/tmp/pids/server.pid.
Exiting